# Python turtle object wont show in window

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am currently trying to make a copy of Atari's breakout using python and turtle. Previously I have created a pong copy which does not use OOP and it worked perfectly fine. However due to the bricks in breakout I decided to use OOP and create an object class for the bricks. Once I run the program, it wont display the brick. Any ideas to why?

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('Atari Breakout')
window.bgcolor('black')
window.setup(width=800, height=600)
window.tracer(0)


class Brick(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='square', visible=True)
        self.myturtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.color = 'white'
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=10, stretch_len=4)
        self.pendown()
        self.goto(-350, 200)


board1 = Brick()
window.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in this code - firstly, you need `turtle.Turtle` not just `Turtle` as otherwise this causes an error. Secondly, the line `self.myturtle = turtle.Turtle()` is unnecessary as `super().__init__(shape='square', visible=True)` already creates a turtle, and thirdly `self.color = 'white'` should be changed to `self.color('white')`. Also, I'm pretty sure you meant `self.penup()` not `self.pendown()` to stop the brick from drawing a line from the center to its position.

Completed code:

```py
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('Atari Breakout')
window.bgcolor('black')
window.setup(width=800, height=600)
window.tracer(0)


class Brick(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='square', visible=True)
        self.color('white')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=10, stretch_len=4)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(-350, 200)


board1 = Brick()
window.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you explaining my errors too cheers mate!